# Solspace User Search not searching email address or screen_name

Tags: solspace

This used to work, but it doesn't now. We're on User 3.4.6 and the changelog for the current version doesn't show any changes that should affect this. I printed the query from function do_search in mod.user.php and it looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(m.member_id) FROM exp_members m LEFT JOIN exp_member_data md ON md.member_id = m.member_id WHERE m.member_id != 0 AND ( m.email LIKE '%johnbogie@domain.com%') AND ( md.m_field_id_8 LIKE '%%' AND md.m_field_id_9 LIKE '%%' AND md.m_field_id_15 LIKE '%%' AND md.m_field_id_16 LIKE '%%' AND md.m_field_id_24 LIKE '%%' AND md.m_field_id_617 LIKE '%%')
```

If I remove the custom member fields and run the query in SQL pro, it works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(m.member_id) FROM exp_members m LEFT JOIN exp_member_data md ON md.member_id = m.member_id WHERE m.member_id != 0 AND ( m.email LIKE '%johnbogie@domain.com%')
```

Here is the form:

```
    <h2>Member Search</h2>
{exp:user:search return="administration/member-search-results"}

    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="text" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="screen_name">Forum Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="screen_name" id="screen_name" class="text" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="cf_member_first_name">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="cf_member_first_name" id="cf_member_first_name" class="text" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="cf_member_last_name">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="cf_member_last_name" id="cf_member_last_name" class="text" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="cf_member_company_name">Company</label>
        <input type="text" name="cf_member_company_name" id="cf_member_company_name" class="text" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="cf_member_region">Region (Non-US &amp; Canada)</label>
        <input type="text" name="cf_member_region" id="cf_member_region" class="text" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="cf_member_state">State (US - Two-letter abbreviation)</label>
        <input type="text" name="cf_member_state" id="cf_member_state" class="text" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="cf_member_province">Province (Canada)</label>
        <input type="text" name="cf_member_province" id="cf_member_province" class="text" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-submit">
        <input type="submit" name="bSubmit" id="bSubmit" class="" value="Search" />
    </div>

{/exp:user:search}
```

Comment: I can var_dump a similar query, but I get the correct results corresponding to my search. Mind you, I was testing with User 3.5.0. Have you tried running that query (the one with m_field_id_Xs) in EE's SQL database query form, or through another DB tool? What results do you get?

Comment: Yes, I had run the query in Sequel Pro and got no results. I went ahead and updated to 3.5.0 and then ran it again, and still get no results. (Yes I fixed the email address being searched) http://cl.ly/image/293W1H122I1x

Comment: I think I found the issue. That query returns no results if your member fields have `NULL` stored in the database in `exp_member_data`. If `NULL` is changed to an empty string, you get a result. Not allowing `NULL` to be stored would make the query work (although it's not the native EE setting), but I'll make a note to our developers about this (perhaps work on a different query approach).